# Changing value of global variable from inside a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried to make a movieclip, then I inserted a script in the movieclip.
so there are two variables, Score as the dynamic text is maintained, and there is a point as the dynamic text inside the movieclip. I want the point value to be moved to the Score when the movie clip is complete. or there might be a way to change the contents of the variable outside the movie clip when the clip movie is executed

```
var point:int = 0;

poin.text = ''+point;
```

this is the code in my movie clip

so how to pass that "point" as dynamic text to "Score" as dynamic text outside the movieclip(on the main timeline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use static variables and without creating an instance of the class, so they can be used as global variables.

Example:

```
package 
{
     class MyClass
     {
         // ...
         public static var myStaticVar: Number;
         // ...
     }
}
```

Then anywhere in your program, you can access the variable myStaticVar this way:

```
MyClass.myStaticVar = 5;
// ...
var value:Number = MyClass.myStaticVar;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: deep thanks from the bottom of my heart, dont know what to say again to express my gratitude

Comment: Thank you my friend. Glad it helped. Keep it rockin.